# Typescript: generic interface, interface functions and class type parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I am trying to implement a generic [discrete interval encoding tree](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/diet/) with typescript. Generic here means I want to allow interval endpoints to be arbitrary classes that extends a simple interface specifying discrete linear orders which enforces the existence of two *method* members `next` and `lessThan`. Because I want to type the methods I assume I need a generic interface (all the code can be found in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/norbusan/1b68eLdr/5048/)):

```
interface DiscreteLinearOrder<T> {
    next = () => T;
    lessThan = (y: T) => Boolean;
}
```

Then I instantiated this with number (ok, it is not discrete, but think of it as integers ;-)

```
class DLOnumber implements DiscreteLinearOrder<number> {
    private value: number;
    constructor(x: number) { this.value = x; }
    next = () => { return(this.value + 1); };
    lessThan = (y: number) => { return(this.value < y); };
    getValue = () => { return(this.value.toString()); }
}
```

Up to here it worked, and running things like

```
const bar = new DLOnumber(5);
```

worked out.

Having this I planed to provide a class `DLOinterval` that takes two parameters, one extending the discrete linear order interface:

```
class DLOinterval<T, U extends DiscreteLinearOrder<T>> {
    private start: U;
    private end: U;
    private data: any;
    constructor(s: U, e: U, d: any) {
        this.start = s;
        this.end   = e;
        this.data  = d;
    }
}
```

But here the troubles are starting: I cannot define a type alias and use it:

```
type NumberInterval = DLOinterval<number, DLOnumber>;
const ggg = new NumberInterval(new DLOnumber(3),new DLOnumber(5),null)
```

neither can I instantiate it directly:

```
const aaa = new DLOinterval<number, DLOnumber>(new DLOnumber(3),new DLOnumber(5),null)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you define NumberInterval as `type NumberInterval = DLOInterval<number, DLOnumber>;`, you are defining a type, not a class constructor, so I don't believe you should be calling `new NumberInterval(...)`.

Also, note that, in `type NumberInterval = DLOInterval<number, DLOnumber>;`, DLOinterval should use a lowercase 'i' (based on your class constructor).

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: This open issue may be relevant here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: AAaah, that is good!!! That is what I am searching for.

Comment: And this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2559

Comment: Your code does not compile with class DLOinterval<T, U extends DiscreteLinearOrder<T>> {
error being, "constraint of a type parameter cannot reference from the same parameter list..." how does it work for you? Please refer to my answer for a working code using your same example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const aaa = new DLOinterval<number, DLOnumber>(new DLOnumber(3), new DLOnumber(5), null);
```

Comment: good point. In the fiddle I actually used T as types for the constructor and call new.. within the constructor, but in both cases I get `ReferenceError: U is not defined`

Comment: Thanks, indeed the type alias didn't work, but direct instantiation does.

Comment: The constructor I had was wrong: `constructor(s: T, e: T, d: any) { this.start = new U(s); ...}` didn't work, U is not defined.

Comment: BTW, do you know why `const bar = new DLOnumber('hello');` this doesn't give an error?

Comment: It does for me: "Argument of type '"hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'."

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a type from the `DLOinterval` class, you can directly use it as follows:

```
const ggg = new DLOinterval<number, DLOnumber>( new DLOnumber(3), new DLOnumber(5), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint applied to `DLOinterval<T, U extends DiscreteLinearOrder<T>>` **doesn't compile** due to the mentioned error in the comment section because it will become like a nested infinite constraint. **How did it work for you?**

The only way it should work correctly is by typing the second constraint as  to get past the compiler's objection to typing the template type as `T`.

```
class DLOinterval<V, U extends DiscreteLinearOrder<any>>
```

To make a working example for a mocha test, I extended the same interface as in the screenshot below:

[image]